# Angular2 not detecting change to object value

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

Basically, i have two components on the parent component i have a object

```
this.data = { startDate : '2016-01-01' };
```

I then have a date picker component which i pass `data.startDate`

However when the date picker component changes the value it doesn't get reflected in the parent components object.

However if i pass this whole object in `data` and then update the value data.startDate inside the child component this does get reflected in the parent. Ideally i don't want to use subscribes and emit events as i want to keep the date picker code quite generic to be reused accross the app.

Any ideas?

Parent ref

`<date-time [dateTimeModel]="data.startDate"></date-time>`

**Child class**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'date-time',
  templateUrl: './dateTime.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dateTime.component.css'],
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: []
})
export class DateTimeComponent  {

  @Input()
  dateTimeModel:any;
  constructor () {}

}
```

**Child Template**

```
<div class="dateTimeInput">
  <label htmlFor="date-1" >Date</label>
  <input type="date" id="date-1" [(ngModel)]="dateTimeModel"   />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your template in which you bind the data.startDate?

Answer (score 3):

Angular2 detects update from references and not from attributes with objects. It's the default behavior of change detection.

If you want to provide custom detection, you could have a look at the `KeyValueDiffer` (object) and `IterableDiffer` (array) classes.

See corresponding codes:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/KeyValueDiffer-interface.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/IterableDiffer-interface.html

**Edit**

If you want to leverage two-way binding for your `DateTimeComponent` you need to use an `@Output`:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'date-time',
  templateUrl: './dateTime.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dateTime.component.css'],
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: []
})
export class DateTimeComponent  {

  @Input()
  dateTimeModel:any;
  @Output()
  dateTimeModelChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor () {}

  onDateUpdated(val) {
    this.dateTimeModelChange.emit(val);
  }
}
```

in the component template:

```
<div class="dateTimeInput">
  <label htmlFor="date-1" >Date</label>
  <input type="date" id="date-1" [ngModel]="dateTimeModel" (ngModelChange)="onDateUpdated($event)"  />
</div>
```

In the parent, you can use it this way:

```
<date-time [(dateTimeModel)]="data.startDate"></date-time>
```

Comment: Ah, was hoping it was something simpler than that. I will take a look, i've also updated the question with a little bit more detail

Comment: I didn't correctly understand your question. I think that you could try the two-way binding on your dateTime component. I updated my answer accordingly...